# How to always open PrimeNg's p-calendar on today's date

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, primeng, primeng-calendar

''I am using PrimeNg's calendar in my Angular Application.  I am using multiple selectionMode and binding the calendar to an array of dates from the database.  The calendar starts on the latest date in the range from the database but I want it to always start off with today's date and then the user can navigate backwards and forwards to see the previously selected dates from the database.  I set the defaultDate but it doesn't make any difference.

Please help.

Thanks,

my html:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="myDates" selectionMode="multiple" [inline]="inline" selectOtherMonths="true" [defaultDate]="defaultDate"></p-calendar>
```

my code:

```
public myDates: Date[] = [];
public defaultDate: Date = new Date();

constructor()
{
    this.myDates.push(new Date('01-01-2017'));
    this.myDates.push(new Date('01-02-2017'));
    this.myDates.push(new Date('01-07-2017'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML
[minDate]="minDateValue"

Ts
this.minDateValue = new Date();

Answer (score 2):

For me works!

In html

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1"></p-calendar>
```

in TS

```
export class CalendarDemo {

    date1: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        let today = new Date();
        this.date1 = today.getMonth() + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi RickG93, Thanks for your reply.  My calendar is selectionMode="multiple" inline="true".  I already have an array of dates bound to my control via [(ngModel)].  I don't want today's date selected (unless that date is in the bound date array).  I want the calendar to be on the month of today's date.  At the moment, if my date array is the 1st and 2nd January 2017, my calendar will be on January 2017.  I want it to be on the current month and year regardless of the bound date array and the user would then have to scroll through the months and years to find the selected date.

Comment: Hi, try add in html p-calendar this: [defaultDate]="defaultDate" and in ts  defaultDate: Date = new Date();

Comment: Hi RikG93, unfortunately I have already tried that and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It's strange, I'm very sorry I can not help you anymore :(

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @LanceM did you figure the resolution for this ?

Comment: @jaibalaji I found setting the minDate seems to work for me.