# Primeng Keep the calendar opened when click onTodayClick

Tags: angular, primeng

there is a possibility to keept the calendar opppend without closing the calendar when click on onTodayClick. The problem is each time I click onTodayClick the calendar closes automatically.

Thank you very much.

Comment: share your code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: What I wan't to achive is when you click on today button I want to keep the calender opened. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xywpgi?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to always open PrimeNg's p-calendar on today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248615/how-to-always-open-primengs-p-calendar-on-todays-date)

Comment: Thank you very much Kiran for your answer, but this is not what I want to do.